# Removal decimals from Quantity on Orders Page

Tags: magento2.2.7

How do I remove the Decimals from the Quantity Column on the Orders Page? The products cannot be ordered in decimals, so the extra characters are pointless.

[image]

Comment: Check from here
>https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109909/magento2-remove-decimal-from-quantity

Comment: It depends which type of products, Magento works by default with 4 decimals for weight and price. And If you want to change it then I would advice against editing the back end to accept just 2.

Comment: You have to change the type of value in this table : catalog_product_entity_decimal

Comment: In your case, you can replace with decimal(12,2) Right now It is decimal(12,4)